# Store LU decomposition of a sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I would like to store the `LU decomposition` of a `sparse matrix A`.
I currently use `scipy.sparse.splu` but the output of this function can't be pickled, and doesn't expose L and U to the user. It only returns an object which has a `solve()` method. Is there any pythonic way to precompute the LU decomposition of A and store it?

Thanks a lot,
Thibault

Comment: This uses a imported compiled library, https://portal.nersc.gov/project/sparse/superlu/.  The decomposition, when/where it exists, would be a C structure, and not something that's available to Python users.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any alternate library / package to do sparse LU decomposition AND store the result?